# How to consume multiple messages with paho client, angular 4

Tags: angular, paho

Im trying to consume 3 values, which i get from a Paho-Client (time, geometry, temperature).The values will be saved in an object named message.
 Now i want to inject the three values throug a Service in my component to save them first in an array. 
So far it is only working by injecting the object(message) with one of the values (message.geometry) in my component. Mi idea is to push messaage.geometry, message.timestamp and message.temperatur. 
This is my **Service** withe the **Paho-Client**

```
@Injectable()
export class GeomqttService {

  client: any;

  geohistory = [
    {
      topic: '',
      timestamp: '',
      payloadstring: '',
      geometry: ''
    }
  ];

  constructor() {
    this.client = new Paho.MQTT.Client('testmqtt.de', 8080, 's');
    this.onConnectionLost();
    this.client.connect({onSuccess: this.onConnected.bind(this)});
  }


  onMessageArrived = (message: Paho.MQTT.Message) => {
    this.geohistory.push({
      'topic': 'temp',
      'timestamp': message.timestamp,
      'payloadstring': message.payloadString,
      'geometry': message.geometry
    });

  };

  onConnected() {
    console.log('Connected');
    this.client.geosubscribe('topic.temperature', '', 'geometry.BBOX(-180 -90, 180 90)', 'INTERSECTS');
    this.client.onMessageArrived = (message: Paho.MQTT.Message) => {
      this.onMessage(message.geometry);
      console.log('Message arrived: ' + message.geometry);
    }
  }

  public onMessage(message: string) {}
```

Here i get the message.geometry, but i would like to inject 3 of the vules in my component, to first save them in an array and use them later on .

My **component**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {GeomqttService} from './geomqtt.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-paho',
  templateUrl: './paho.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./paho.component.css']
})
export class PahoComponent implements OnInit {


  data = [
    {
      topic: '',
      timestamp: '',
      payloadstring: '',
      geometry: ''
    }
  ];


  constructor(private geomqttService: GeomqttService) {
    this.geomqttService.onMessage = (message: string) => {
      this.data = [{topic: 'test', timestamp: '' , payloadstring: '', geometry: message}];
      console.log(this.data);
    };
  }

  ngOnInit(){}

}
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Can you try to re-formulate it?

Comment: I edited my question, hopefully it's now more precise.

Comment: Thanks. Your `onMessage` implementation is empty. Is that intended? Does `geosubscribe` return an `observable` you can subscribe to?

Comment: That is more or less intended, because i am using the onMessage method just for the object (message. string) in several components. Yes, geosubscribe is returning an observable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to the changes of the `GeomqttService` service and then pass them either to your component or a stream as shown below.

In your service, create a public `onMessage` variable that will notify any subscribers when the data has arrived.

```
@Injectable()
export class GeomqttService {
  ...
  public onMessage: new Subject();

  onConnected() {
    console.log('Connected');
    this.client.geosubscribe('topic.temperature', '', 'geometry.BBOX(-180 -90, 180 90)', 'INTERSECTS').subcribe((message:message: Paho.MQTT.Message) => {
      // call any other method here if you like.
      onMessage.next(message);
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

In your component then, you can subscribe to the `onMessage` subject to get the latest data and change it the way you need.

```
export class PahoComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  constructor(private geomqttService: GeomqttService) {
    this.geomqttService.onMessage = (message: Paho.MQTT.Message) => {
      console.log(message);
    };
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: There is a lot of code missing to realize your solution and i didnt really get the idea of your solution, to implement it by myself.

Comment: The answer isn't usefull in this state, perhaps you could add some more information...

Comment: My idea is that you need to subscribe to the HTTP calls and return the data to the component when it is has received it. In your original code, you are not subscribing to the HTTP call. Its unclear to me how you are retrieving the message initially.

Comment: I get the message as object from my Service without problems. In my original code i am subscribing to my onConnected method, with the onMessage method inside! So this is already working. But my question is more about how to get the 3 values from the object message in my Service, to show them in my component seperatly? I want to get acces to message.geometry, message.timestamp and message.payloadstring to do different things with them in my component!

Comment: Does `onMessage` return all three properties? Could you create a reproducible stackblitz?

Comment: That is the point! onMessage can just return message.payloadstring OR message.timestamp OR message.geometry... Mi idea was to have i like: this.onMessage(message.timestamp, message.geometry, message.payloadstring) But this isn't working...

Comment: i cant build a stackblitz, because i am using my own js lib for an geo version of the paho-client...

Comment: Do you have to make a separate http call to get each property?